# CIImage to UIImage Distorts Color SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiimage, ciimage

I've run across an issue where I've converted images from CIImage => UIImage and the colors become distorted somewhere in the conversion.

The test case I've set up is a pure blue image that I open with CIImage and an url to the path.  I convert it to UIImage using what I thought was pretty standard way of converting CIImage to UIImage, i.e. CIContext:createCGImage, then check one of the pixels.

Expected:

```
pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 0.0 : 1.0 : 1.0
```

Actual:

```
pixelColor :: rgba : 0.0 : 0.1803921568627451 : 1.0 : 1.0
```

Anyways, if anybody can point out why this is happening, I would appreciated it.  Thanks.

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Blue", ofType: "png") else { // RGBA 0, 0, 255, 0
  debugPrint("File :: Blue not found")
  return
}
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

if let ciImage = CIImage(contentsOf: url) {
  let converted = convert(ciImage: ciImage)
  let _ = converted.getPixelColor(pos: pixelPoint)
}
```

--

```
func convert(ciImage:CIImage) -> UIImage
{
    let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
    let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)!
    let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    return image
}
```

--

```
extension UIImage {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

    let pixelData = self.cgImage!.dataProvider!.data
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

    let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
    let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

    print("pixelColor :: rgba : \(r) : \(g) : \(b) : \(a)")

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my convert function was not correctly initializing the CIContext.  Here's the corrected method:

```
  func convert(ciImage:CIImage) -> UIImage?
  {
    let context = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.workingColorSpace: kCFNull!])
    if let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent, format: .RGBA8, colorSpace: CGColorSpace.init(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!) {
      let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
      return image
    }
    return nil
  }
```